# Работа с меню

Tags: php

Подскажите, пожалуйста, вот в чем. Есть меню сайта. Код:

```
<?php
error_reporting(E_ALL);
mysql_connect("localhost", "root", "");
mysql_select_db("BD");

$q = 'select * from tema';
$r = mysql_query($q);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
    echo "{$row['naz_tema']}<p>";

    $w = "select * from razdel where tema_num_tema={$row['num_tema']}";

    $e = mysql_query($w);

    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($e)) {
        echo " <p>{$row1['naz_razdel']}<p>";
    }
}
?>
```

Теперь как по клику на одном из пунктов сделать показ страницы, который соответствует выбранному пункту?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Можно по уникальному ключу выводить данные из БД. Например по ID

```
$sql = (isset($_GET['id'])) ? "where `id` = '".intval($_GET['id'])."' " : "";
$q = 'select * from tema '.$sql;

$r = mysql_query($q);
while ($row = mysql_fetch_array($r)) {
    echo "{$row['naz_tema']}<p>";

    $w = "select * from razdel where tema_num_tema={$row['num_tema']}";

    $e = mysql_query($w);

    while ($row1 = mysql_fetch_array($e)) {
        echo " <p>{$row1['naz_razdel']}<p>";
    }
}
```

Только вот, что вы подразумиваете под "пунктом" ?

Comment: Есть разделы и подразделы. Так же пункты и подпункты. И то, что написано пункт, это есть подпункт.
`$w = "select * from razdel where tema_num_tema={$row['num_tema']}";`
эта строка отвечает за выборку подпунктов, которые и будут активными ссылками. На клике которых осуществлялся показ страницы. Просто непонятно, где писать код? В том же файле, где и меню? И как его "склеить" с главной страницей?